# Upload multiple files - Incomplete script

Tags: c#, jquery, html, file-upload

Just got my hand on a script that I wish to use to upload files in my application. I can't really use any of the existing controls as I need to do some specific alterations to paths and stuff before the files are uploaded.

I have the following (incomplete) code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="../plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<span class="btn btn-file btn-primary" id="media-upload-btn">
    <span class="fileupload-new" title="Accepted formats (.gif, .jpeg, .png)">Choose image(s)</span>
    <span class="fileupload-exists">Choose another image</span>
    <input id="user-file-to-upload" type="file" name="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"/>
</span><br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="upload();" value="Upload" />

</form>

</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function upload() {
        alert("test");
        // var acceptedFileSize = $('#upload-image-size').val();
        var acceptedFileSize = 10000;
        alert(acceptedFileSize);

        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var data = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
                var fileSize = files[i].size;
                sp.base.log('fileSize(b): ' + fileSize);
                sp.base.log('acceptedFileSize(kb): ' + acceptedFileSize);
                if (parseInt(fileSize) > (parseInt(acceptedFileSize) * 1024)) {
                    $('#btnUpload').button('reset');
                    sp.base.show('The file is too large!<br>Cant be larger than ' + (parseInt(acceptedFileSize) / 1024) + ' MB. ' + ' and the current file size is ' + Math.round((parseInt(fileSize) / 1024 / 1024)) + ' MB.', 'error', 12000);
                    return false;
                }
            }



            var url = "upload2.aspx";

            sp.base.call(
            'POST',
            url,
            data,
            function (returnData) {
                alert("Works");
                onSuccessUploadImage(returnData, callback);
            },
            null,
            function () {
                // onError
                alert("Error");
                $('#btnUpload').button('reset');
            },
            null,
            true,
            false
        );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Right now, I'm unsure of how to actually collect the files into the files object, and I would also like to be able to add multiple files, not just one.